# DateTime picker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

Im having MVC5 project and I want to add date picker ,currently its not working since I've error in the JS code,what am I missing here ?
I try to add Nuget for datetime picker as follows but its not working.
the error in the console is

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Create:93
(anonymous function) Create:93
```

Any idea what am I missing here?

this is all the page code

I can share the project if its needed this is very simple project with 3 fields

```
@model TestropDownCreate.Models.TestModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>    

<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>    
<script src="~/Scripts/moment-datepicker.js"></script>            
<link href="~/Content/moment-datepicker/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<link href="~/Content/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />    



<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>    

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Model</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name) 

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedGender, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedGender, Model.Gender)

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-append date control-label col-md-2">
                Date
                <input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" type="text" id="datetimepicker4" />
                <span class="add-on">
                    <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
                </span>
            </div>

        </div>


       // It's there where I'm having the error -->

            <script type="text/javascript">

                $(function () {

                    $('#datetimepicker4').datepicker({

                        pickTime: false

                    });

                });

            </script>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: In addition to the duplicate .min scripts, you also appear to have more than one date picker library. Choose one as the others will likely conflict with each other.

Comment: @Jasen-I remove all the duplicate and having the same issue...I update the post with what I changed pls have a look

Comment: You code still contains two datepicker libraries: `moment-datepicker.js` and `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js`. You also make use of the `pickTime` option. Where did you get that option from? Use that library and remove the other.

Comment: Also note that there are multiple "bootstrap datepickers" from different authors. It will be helpful to link exactly where you got that particular script so others can reproduce your example.

Comment: @Jasen- HI Jasen all the reference that I add is from Nuget ,I can share the project if you have time...

Comment: NuGet packages usually have a project reference page -- that would be sufficient.

Comment: @Jasen- I remove all and put just this tree and still I have the issue :( ,any idea? <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>    

<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>    

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: Have you got any other error in your console (some script not loaded or something like that)? And as Jasen told you, you have to chose the datepicker framework you want to use!

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie-yes I've error in jqueryboundle that I notice just now...

Answer (score 0):

One of the mistakes I found in your code is that you are including same script twice - once the normal version and second the minified version.

Like this-

```
<script src="~/Scripts/moment-datepicker.js"></script>   
<script src="~/Scripts/moment-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

You are supposed to include only one of those. So, either include

```
<script src="~/Scripts/moment-datepicker.js"></script>
```

OR

```
<script src="~/Scripts/moment-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Same goes with other scripts that you have included twice.

Hopefully, if you fix that, it will fix your issue unless there are more mistakes in your code.

Comment: Ok I remove all the MIN and ive just the following but the same issue happen... <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>    

<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>    

<script src="~/Scripts/moment-datepicker.js"></script>   
           
<link href="~/Content/moment-datepicker/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<link href="~/Content/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>